# How to test rails file upload failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

There's lots of good stuff on how to test a Rails file upload, but how can I simulate a failure to test what happens in this case?  For example if there is some reason that the storage is temporarily unavailable, I would like the user to see a sensible error.
Can I somehow simulate this sort of failure using minitest?

Comment: Did you consider to stub the method on Tempfile that is used to write the data into that file and let it raise an error?

Comment: Excellent.  I'd not come across stubbing although I imagined there would be something that did something similar - it's all about knowing the correct term to search for ;-).